# export a environment variable for terraform does not work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

i am trying to set a environment variable for terraform

using `export TF_VAR_instanceType="t2.nano"`

my tf file looks something like this:-

```
resource "aws_instance" "myFirstEc2Instance" {

  ami           = "ami-0ca285d4c2cda3300"
  instance_type = var.instanceType
}
```

Note there is terraform.tfvars as well as variables.tf files too, i am trying to see how exporting environment variables work in Mac.
It is using value present terraform.tfvars file.

Comment: have you declared the instanceType as a variable? It is not enough to pass the TF_VAR_var variable. You need to define it in terraform:

variable "instanceType" {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because terraform uses `TF_VAR` as a fallback. So, if it finds the variable in `terraform.tfvars` it'll use the value. If not, then it'll search for other instances and use the *last* one it finds.

> As a fallback for the other ways of defining variables, Terraform searches the environment of its own process for environment variables named TF_VAR_ followed by the name of a declared variable.

[Source](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#environment-variables)

> if the same variable is assigned multiple values, Terraform uses the last value it finds, overriding any previous values. **Note that the same variable cannot be assigned multiple values within a single source.**

So, this looks like:

- Environment variables
- The terraform.tfvars file, if present.
- The terraform.tfvars.json file, if present.
- Any *.auto.tfvars or *.auto.tfvars.json files, processed in lexical order of their filenames.
- Any -var and -var-file options on the command line, in the order they are provided. (This includes variables set by a Terraform Cloud workspace.)

[Source](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#variable-definition-precedence)

Comment: thank you @baduker for the source links and clear explanation.